# How to parse arbitrary dates with datejs parseExact

Tags: javascript, date, formatting, datejs

I want to parse a date in this format '11h04 31/05/2011' and other arbitrary formats using datejs, I tried:

```
Date.parseExact("11h04 31/05/2011", "HH'h'mm dd/MM/yyyy")
```

and

```
Date.parseExact("11h04 31/05/2011", "HH\hmm dd/MM/yyyy")
```

without success.
Does anyone knows the exact format/specification of parseExact or how to parse this (and others) arbitrary formats?

In java i would do this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH'h'mm dd/MM/yyyy");
sdf.parse(date);
```

P.S.: yeah, I know I can use a regex to split the string and then parse, but I want to know how to parse it with parseExact.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at the date.js source, I don't see that it makes any attempt to understand "escapes" or literals in the format specifiers.

Answer (score 2):

`Does anyone knows the exact format/specification of parseExact`

Here is a link to the date.js format specifiers used by date.js and parseExact

http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/FormatSpecifiers#CUSTOM_DATE_AND_TIME_FORMAT_SPECIFIERS

I can't find any way to trick the parseExact method into thinking the formatString doesn't contain a literal h between HH and mm.  Tried \u0068, \0x68, no luck.

I think your best bet is

```
var date = "11h04 31/05/2011";
Date.parseExact(date.replace("h",""),"HHmm dd/MM/yyyy")
```